# Exception ignore error when adding timeout function for asyncio.subprocess.communicate() in python 3

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio

I'm trying to add timeout function when using asyncio.subprocess. I start a subprocess to execute some commands, if it takes too long time, I want to make it failed and terminate the process. In terms of official document, I use asyncio.wait_for to implement it. Here is the sample code:

```
async def ping():
    cmd = 'ping localhost'
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(cmd, 
    stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    try:
        stdout, _ = await asyncio.wait_for(proc.communicate(), 3)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('Timeout')
        return 'Cancelled'
    finally:
        proc.terminate()

    return stdout.decode().strip()

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() #on windows, use another event loop to support subprocess
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(ping())
    result = loop.run_until_complete(task)
    print(f'the result is {result}')
    loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can always get the result, no matter it's succeed or timeout. But got an error in console when I running it.

On macOS, it likes:

```
Exception ignored when trying to write to the signal wakeup fd:
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

On Windows, it likes: Event loop is closed, The task is destroyed but it's pending. Apologize I can't remember it clearly, I'm testing on mac now.

I checked some answers, and refer to document, wait_for raise a TimeoutError and cancel wrapped coroutine. But because the task is not cancelled immediately, it will be cancelled in next loop. But at that moment, the event loop is already closed in my program.

So my problem is what's the proper way to handle this kind of issue. Should I care about this error? Because I can always get the result I want.

Comment: In this program it's safe to just remove `loop.close()`, since the program is about to exit anyway. I think you should be able to add `await proc.wait()` after the terminate, but that results in another warning, for which I've now [filed an issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue35539).

Comment: Thanks, resolve this issue by adding await proc.wait(). Has to wait the task to be cancelled